# Application Bar Button Command and Can Execute Method

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, prism

I have an application bar button that I have hooked up to a command using Prism like so:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <prismInteractivity:ApplicationBarButtonCommand ButtonText="save" CommandBinding="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

The save command looks like this:

```
SaveCommand = new RelayCommand( Save, CanSave );
```

The `CanSave` method is only getting called when the page loads. The button then gets disabled because `false` is returned the first time (due to validation).

How can I get the CanSave method to fire again so it can be enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out by looking at the source to the TailSpin Prism demo app.

When you want it to fire again, like when text in a text box has changed, just call:

```
SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

So, in my case, when the `Name` property is set, I want it to run again.

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        name = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged( () => Name );
        SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for answering your own question. Few people take the time to do that.